# Python timer countdown

Tags: python, timer, countdown

I want to know about timer in Python.

Suppose i have a code snippet something like:

```
def abc()
   print 'Hi'  
   print 'Hello'
   print 'Hai'
```

And i want to print it every 1 second. Max three times;ie; 1st second i need to check the printf, 2nd second I need to check as well in 3rd second.

In my actual code variables value will be updated.
I need to capture at what second all the variables are getting updated.

Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Comment: do you want to print each line after a delay of `n` seconds?

Comment: OT - good greif! Out of 68 quesitons you've only accepted 29%? You /really/ need to go and accept answers to more of your questions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `time.sleep`.

```
import time

def abc():
    print 'Hi'
    print 'Hello'
    print 'Hai'

for i in xrange(3):
    time.sleep(1)
    abc()
```

Comment: within 1 second I need to print. In the above program after giving 1 sec delay its been printed. I want it within 1 sec.
My program will contain variables which will be getting updated. What I want is to monitor how many seconds it is taking for all the variables to get updated.

Answer (score 8):

`time.sleep` is fine in this case but what if the `abc()` function takes half a second to execute? Or 5 minutes?
In this case you should use a `Timer` object.

```
from threading import Timer

def abc():
    print 'Hi'  
    print 'Hello'
    print 'Hai'

for i in xrange(3):
    Timer(i, abc).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into `time.sleep()`.  For example:

```
for i in xrange(5):
  abc()
  time.sleep(3)
```

That will print your lines 5 times with a 3 second delay between.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def abc()
    for i in range(3):
        print 'Hi'  
        print 'Hello'
        print 'Hai'
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def abc():
 print 'Hi'
 print 'Hello'
 print 'Hai'

for i in range(3):
 time.sleep(3-i)
 abc()
```

Answer (score 0):

usually for me this works...

```
import time

def abc():
    print 'Hi'
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Hello'
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Hai'
    time.sleep(1)
```

I think you can guess after that...

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
import time

c=':'
sec = 0
min = 0
hour = 0

#count up clock

while True:
for y in range(59):                                                 #hours
    for x in range (59):                                            #min
        sec = sec+1
        sec1 = ('%02.f' % sec)                                      #format
        min1 = ('%02.f' % min)
        hour1= ('%02.f' % hour)
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+str(hour1)+c+str(min1)+c+str(sec1))   #clear and write
        time.sleep(1)
    sec = 0
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(hour1) + c + str(min1) + c + '00')  #ensure proper timing and display
    time.sleep(1)
    min=min+1
min = 0
sys.stdout.write('\r' + str(hour1) + c + str(min1) + c + '00')      #ensure proper timing and display
time.sleep(1)
hour=hour+1
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation on how this works. Code dumping is frowned upon here.