# Executing a function every 1 second

Tags: python, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python timer countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309664/python-timer-countdown)

Hi guys,

I want to know about timer in Python.

Suppose i have a code snippet something like:

```
def abc()
   print 'Hi'  
   print 'Hello'
   print 'Hai'
```

And i want to print it every 1 second. Max three times;ie; 1st second i need to check the printf, 2nd second I need to check as well in 3rd second.

In my actual code variables value will be updated.
I need to capture at what second all the variables are getting updated.

Can anybody tell me how to do this.

Comment: exact duplicate of [Python timer countdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309664/python-timer-countdown)

Comment: why are you adding same question twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a while loop, and the `time` module, with `time.sleep` to wait one second, and `time.clock` to know at what time you print your variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can see, if you can utilize the [sched](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) module from the standard library:

> The sched module defines a class which implements a general purpose event scheduler.

```
>>> import sched, time
>>> s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
>>> def print_time(): print "From print_time", time.time()
...
>>> def print_some_times():
...     print time.time()
...     s.enter(5, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.enter(10, 1, print_time, ())
...     s.run()
...     print time.time()
...
>>> print_some_times()
930343690.257
From print_time 930343695.274
From print_time 930343700.273
930343700.276
```